# React Material UI: How to prevent the Popover component overlay the screen when Menu component opens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `Menu` component to show up a menu when user hovers on an element. However, I noticed that when the menu opens up it also contains a `Popover` component that opens up and covers the entire screen as an overlay thus preventing interaction with the screen. I do not want the overlay to open when I open the `Menu` component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which component is this Menu ? The one from Material UI ? I don't see this popover on the Menu example from the documentation

Comment: I guess you forgot to paste your code... :)

Comment: Tried the Popper component? https://material-ui.com/components/popper/

Comment: Any update on this? I created a ticket on the material-ui page:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26362

Answer (score 7):

The `Menu` Component inherits from `Popover`, which inherits from `Modal`. So all `Modal` props are also available to `Menu`. The ones that might help you;

- `hideBackdrop`: If `true`, the backdrop is not rendered.
- `disableScrollLock`: Disable the scroll lock behavior.

More at https://material-ui.com/api/modal/ .